# Systemd - How to trigger another unit while reloading a service?

Tags: linux, systemd, teleport

I'm currently facing the issue that I want to trigger a Systemd unit when another unit get reloaded - not restartet. This is what I achived so far:

```
[Unit]
After=teleport.service
Requires=teleport.service
PartOf=teleport.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "Reloaded gracefully | /usr/bin/logger"
```

But that is only working using systemctl restart teleport. Reload doesn't work. How can this be achived without touching the original teleport.service unit?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about systemd, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but rahter configuring it, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on the [unix stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that this can be easily achived by drop-in files. Instead of writing a new unit drop-in files can be used like this:

You can create drop-in files in /etc/systemd/... for units defined in /lib or /usr/lib:
/etc/systemd/system/teleport.service.d/override.conf

```
[Service] 
ExecReload=
ExecReload=/usr/bin/bash -c "/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID; usr/bin/bash -c "Reloaded gracefully | /usr/bin/logger"
```

First the defined attribute needs to be unset. What happens directly after [Service].